# Delete comments directly from the activity list

Tags: feature-request, comments

I sometimes try to do my little share of removing junk from the sites I participate in. One of the things is to remove old comments that were useful at the time, but now only add noise.

Some comments must be judged in their context to see if they're still useful, others are clearly expired without looking any further. For these it would be *really* nice to be able to delete comments directly in the activity list. Would this be a useful (and doable) feature?

[image]

Comment: I can see a limited benefit for this, but I don't think it is worth the effort to implement.

Comment: *"Some comments must be judged in their context to see if they're still useful"* -- indeed. But then allowing for deletion through the activity might yield a lot of orphaned responses (for comments that got replies) if someone uses that for bulk deletion? (As an aside, I don't think your "+1" example qualifies as *"old comments that were useful at the time"*...)

Comment: @Arjan Oh boy, I thought it did... Anyway, yes, to be used with caution.